# Don't have access to post meta in save_post action

Tags: php, wordpress

So what I've noticed is that if I check for a meta value in my save_post function, it comes as blank, meaning the meta value hasn't actually been entered into the post. Looking at this code for example,

```
function order_mirror_create($post_id) {

    global $post;

    if($post->ID == ''){
            $pid = $post_id;
    } else {
            $pid = $post->ID;
    }

    $videohost = get_post_meta($pid, 'video_provider', true);


    if ($videohost == "UploadAnime") {

        add_post_meta($pid, 'video_display_order', 1, true);

    } else {

        add_post_meta($pid, 'video_display_order', $videohost, true);

    }

}
```

`$videohost` is actually blank, so  `get_post_meta($pid, 'video_provider', true)` does not return the actual value of that meta field because it hasn't been created yet.

So in the code above, the `else` is always the one that runs, since `$videohost` is blank. How can I fix this? What `action` should I use that would run in such a manner that the post meta have already been added to the post.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the following:

```
if ($videohost == "UploadAnime") {

        add_post_meta($pid, 'video_display_order', 1, true);

    } else {

        add_post_meta($pid, 'video_display_order', $videohost, true);

    }
```

To:

```
if ($videohost == "UploadAnime") {

        update_post_meta($pid, 'video_display_order', 1, true);

    } else {

        update_post_meta($pid, 'video_display_order', $videohost, true);

    }
```

I find add_post_meta has never really worked for me, whereas update_post_meta does.

Comment: `update_post_meta` simply calls `add_post_meta` when it sees that no meta field is actually created. In essence, it should never be actually updating the meta value ever, so it'll always be calling `add_post_meta`....

In any case, `add_post_meta` works fine, the fact that it's adding blank values tells me that `$videohost` has nothing in it, which is why the else statement is always running.